# Lowest number of positive integers less than or equal to 14 where at least 3 pairs of integers have the same difference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is asking for the minimum number of positive integers less than or equal to 14, where there are at least 3 pairs of integers have the same absolute difference. eg. pair ${a,b}$ has a an absolute difference of $|a - b|$.

I'm not sure how to find the solution to this question using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Are you asking for the least natural number $n$ such that for all subsets $S\subseteq \{1,\cdots,14\}$ of cardinality $n$ there are three distinct subsets $\{a_1,b_1\}$, $\{a_2,b_2\}$, $\{a_3,b_3\}\subseteq S$ of cardinality $2$ such that $| a_1-b_1|=| a_2-b_2|=| a_3-b_3|$, or are you asking for the least natural number $n$ such that there is a subset $S\subseteq \{1,\cdots,14\}$ of cardinality $n$ such that there are three distinct subsets $\{a_1,b_1\}$, $\{a_2,b_2\}$, $\{a_3,b_3\}\subseteq S$ of cardinality $2$ such that $\lvert a_1-b_1\rvert=\lvert a_2-b_2\rvert=\lvert a_3-b_3\rvert$?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: I don't know about using pigeonhole, but it's pretty apparent that the number is $4$ because $4$ works and with $3$ elements $a<b<c$ you end up having just three subsets of $2$ elements in total. In which case, by hypothesis $\lvert c-a\rvert\ne \lvert c-b\rvert$.